# Unable to connect from bitbucket pipelines to shared hosting via ssh

Tags: ssh, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

What I need to do is to SSH public server (which is shared hosting) and run a script that starts the deployment process.

I followed what's written [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-ssh-keys-in-bitbucket-pipelines-847452940.html?_ga=2.131715462.869468983.1566040991-1775430450.1554817439):

- I've created a key pair in `Settings > Pipelines > SSH Keys`
- Then I've added the IP address of the remote server
- Then I've appended the public key to the remote server's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file

When I try to run this pipeline:

```
image: img-name
pipelines:
   branches:
      staging:
        - step:
            deployment: Staging
            script:
              - ssh remote_username@remote_ip:port ls -l
```

I have the following error:

> Could not resolve hostname remote_ip:port: Name or service not known

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSH command doesn't take the `ip:port` syntax. You'll need to use a different format:

`ssh -p port user@remote_ip "command"`

(This assumes that your `remote_ip` is publicly-accessible, of course.)

Comment: Ahh, this works. I didn't think of that. Thank you so much!